# Boundness theorem on convergent sequences

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

[image]

In part(b) what does $d(x,y)$ mean? Does it mean the distance between the sequences? Can someone give an example. Does it hold True for all sequences?

How can a distance metric be defined for both individual terms as well as sequences?

Answer (score 1):

$d(x,y)$ is the distance between the 2 elements $x$ and $y$ of $X$, which are the limits of the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ resp. This isn't a distance between the sequences! This property holds true for all convergent sequences in a metric space.

**Example:** in $(\mathbb R,|\cdot|)$, this means that if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$, then $|x_n-y_n|\to |x-y|$. For example, if $\,\forall n\in\mathbb N, x_n=\dfrac 1n$ and $y_n = 3+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, then this means that $$|x_n-y_n|\to |0-3| = 3.$$